# Spring Cloud AWS SecretsManagerClient not available in Spring application context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aws-secrets-manager, spring-cloud-aws

I'm uncertain why there is no SecretsManagerClient available in my Spring application context.

https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/index.html#using-secretsmanagerclient

> The starter automatically configures and registers a SecretsManagerClient bean in the Spring application context. The SecretsManagerClient bean can be used to create or retrieve secrets imperatively.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>secret-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>secret-test</name>
    <description>secret-test</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <software.amazon.awssdk.version>2.22.12</software.amazon.awssdk.version>
        <spring-cloud-aws.version>3.1.0</spring-cloud-aws.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-aws.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>${software.amazon.awssdk.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-starter-secrets-manager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

```
@Service
public class SecretService {
   @Autowired
   private SecretsManagerClient secretsClient;
}
```

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field secretsClient in org.foo.secrettest.SecretService required a
> bean of type
> 'software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.SecretsManagerClient'
> that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.SecretsManagerClient'
> in your configuration.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I could create a SecretsManagerClient @Bean but then it won't be automatically configured with the values in application.yaml.

Ultimately, I'd like to use

```
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: localstack
  cloud:
    aws:
      secretsmanager:
        endpoint: http://localhost:4566
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: adding spring.config.import: optional:aws-secretsmanager:/my/dummy/secret allows this to work.  This seems like a bug in the initialization.  I shouldn't be required to load secrets at startup to use Secrets Manager.  Could there be another configuration that I'm missing here?